# Exercise in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I look for solutions to the following problem.

**Exercise.** How many different three-digit numbers can be made with 3 fours, 4 twos, and 2 threes.

Unfortunately I don't have any idea how to approach to the solution.
It looks like many technique might be applied here.
Please share with us all idea that you have towards the solution.

Comment: Perhaps you should break out cases based on how many fours are used (in your three-digit numbers).

Comment: The Question seems to allow for a quite different interpretation than the one I originally understood (and which the responses below cover).  One might ask, since there are nine digits available (3 fours, 4 twos, and 2 threes) if it is possible to arrange them to get 3 different three-digit numbers, using all the available digits.  Of course the answer to that would be yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:  What would the answer be if there was an *unlimited* number of fours, twos, and threes?  How many (if any) of them violate the actual given restrictions?

Comment: Great hint. I think you should add more details, considering that there is a tedious approach written out.

Comment: Do you mean, that the total number of arrangements is $3*3*3 = 27$, however $333$ is impossible, therefore we have only 26. Right?

Comment: @user16168, exactly!

Answer (score 3):

model the digit as boxes to be filled.so what you have is four 2's ,two 3's,three 4's.
Remove identical cases e.g it doesn't matter which one of the two 3's you use.

1. using one of the three only, two places remain.so 2X2=4.three such cases for different positions of the 3.so 4X3=12
2. using two of the three, one places remain.so 2 ways to fill it.three such cases for different positions of the 3.so 2X3=6.
3. using no three,total no. of numbers possible= 2X2X2=8.

This had to be done because we had only two 3's which was less than the total no. of digits.Hence answer is 12+6+8=26